# Where is $PATH with bash --norc --noprofile documented?

Tags: bash, shell, path

If I run bash with a clean environment, I'd expect the PATH to be empty, however:

```
odin ~ 210$ env -i bash --norc --noprofile 
bash-4.4$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
bash-4.4$ uname -a
Linux odin 4.10.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 14:38:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bash-4.4$
```

The PATH is not empty.

I've been through the documentation a couple of times, but perhaps I
missed something.

My question: where is this documented?

Thanks.

-E

Comment: I've found a couple of clues in `man bash`. (1) In the documentation of the `PATH` variable, `The  search  path  for  commands. ... The default path is system-dependent, and is set by the administrator who installs bash.  A common value is "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin"`. (2) In `command [-pVv] command [arg ...]` documentation, `Run command with args suppressing the normal shell function lookup. ... If  the  -p option  is  given,  the  search  for  command is performed using a default value for PATH that is guaranteed to find all of the standard utilities. ...`.

Comment: Splendid!  Thanks!  I was reading the `info` documentation since it is usually more complete.  Shows what I know.  If you put it in an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a couple of clues in `man bash`.

(1) In the documentation of the PATH variable:-

> PATH   The  search  path  for  commands. It is a colon-separated list of
>          directories in which the shell looks for commands (see COMMAND
>          EXECUTION below).  A zero-length (null) directory name in the value
>          of PATH indicates the current directory.  A null directory name may
>          appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon.
>          **The default path is system-dependent, and is set by the administrator
>          who installs bash. A common value is
>          ``/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin''.**

(2) In the documentation of `command`:-

> command [-pVv] command [arg ...]   Run command with args suppressing
>   the
>          normal shell function lookup.  Only builtin commands or commands
>          found in the  PATH  are  executed.   **If  the  -p  option  is  given,
>          the  search  for  command is performed using a default value for PATH
>          that is guaranteed to find all of the standard utilities.**
>          ...

On Ubuntu 18.04.2 I get the same `PATH` variable. I noted two things:-

1. This `PATH` includes `.`, but this is generally ill-advised.
2. In the new `bash` instance, `declare -p PATH` shows that `PATH` is not exported, as in the normal configuration, so `env` does not show `PATH` in its environment list.

Comment: "Where is it documented?"  The `man` page.  Duh.  In my defense, most GNU commands say, "Full documentation ... available locally via: info"  The `bash` manual *does not* say this.

Comment: Most `info` pages contain the `man` information, with additions sometimes. I've not looked at `info bash` before, but quite a lot is missing from the `man` pages. I learned Linux on System V, so `man` is what I first think of.